# Печать перед исключением не работает

Tags: c++, исключения, вывод, printf

Почему программа не печатает `1`? Как сделать чтобы печатала?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>

int main() {
    std::printf("1");
    throw std::exception{};
    std::printf("2");
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: @Chorkov там на пиндоском

Comment: буфер нужно сбросить скорее всего

Comment: @Ildar какой и куда

Comment: Попробуйте так: `std::printf("1\n");`. Или так - добавив `std::fflush(stdout);` после `std::printf("1");`.
А вообще, зависит от компилятора. У меня на VC++ вполне выводит...

Comment: @Harry не работает

Answer (score 0):

потоки ввода вывода в c++ буферизированы для уменьшения частоты обращения к ним, чтобы увеличить производительность

чтобы сбросить буфер используйте `fflush`, а вообще в c++ стоит пользоваться обьектами `cin cout` для стандартного ввода вывода

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>

int main() 
{
  std::printf("1");
  std::fflush(stdout);
  throw std::exception{};
  std::printf("2");
}
```

Comment: так я не использую потоки

Comment: @kururum это абстракция неявно используемая при обращении к стандартному вводу выводу

Comment: не, потоки это `iostream`, а я использую `printf`

Comment: всё равно `fflush` не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашол решение сам

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>

int main() 
{
  std::fprintf(stderr,"1");
  throw std::exception{};
  std::fprintf(stderr,"2");
}
```

Comment: правильно, потому что stderr - не буферизированный.

Comment: А можно ещё вот так `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` и тогда prinft будет работать как Вам хочется

Comment: Только это не то решение, так как вы используете уже другой поток вывода.